# Social Sharing link of LinkedIn just does not work, when js file is included dynamically

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, linkedin-api

Social Sharing link of LinkedIn just does not work in `Firefox`, when js file is included dynamically.

See the online [problem demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yJRur/).

I have following html containing facebook, twitter and linked share links:

```
<a id="FBshare_{{MashupId}}" name="fb_share" type="box_count" share_url="http://google.com"></a>
&nbsp;
<a id="TWshare_{{MashupId}}" href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" data-url="http://google.com">Tweet</a>
&nbsp;
<script data-counter="top" type="in/share" data-url="http://google.com"></script>
```

And following javascript code:

```
// this script just does not work, I dont know why.
$.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js");

$.getScript("http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share");

$.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
```

But for some reason the linked script does not work, and linked sharing link does not show.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The linkedin code on your jsFiddle is working perfectly for me in Firefox.  Try updating your firefox to the latest version.  Mine is v 8.0